# perf, how can I obtain the memory address of load/store instructions on an Arm machine?

Tags: performance, arm, perf

```
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_RAW;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = 0x13;
    pe.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_ADDR | PERF_SAMPLE_TID;
    pe.disabled = 0;
    pe.sample_period = 1;
    pe.precise_ip = 1;
```

The `pe.config` 0x13 is copied from libpfm4: [arm_cortex_a57_events](https://github.com/wcohen/libpfm4/blob/master/lib/events/arm_cortex_a57_events.h)

```
    {.name = "DATA_MEM_ACCESS",
     .modmsk = ARMV8_ATTRS,
     .code = 0x13,
     .desc = "Data memory access"
    },
```

Howerver addr = 0.

What is the correct code of pe.config? How can I get the right code?